# Best parallel method for finding roots of a numerical function

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, numerical-methods

In some number crunching application, I need to find the multiple (undefined number, bigger or equal to zero) real roots of some numerical function in one dimension produced during the simulation and for which there is not analytical expression.

Given a required accuracy, I wonder which is the best (fastest) parallel method/algorithm for doing this.

Comment: How is the function stored/calculated? Is it a number of x, f(x) pairs or what? Do you know anything regarding the properties of the function, e.g. is it continuous?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to save parallelism for some other thing ? I mean if you are for instance going to solve for this function multiple times, you don't have to parallelize the solver: only the calls to the solver need to be done in parallel. Indeed, I don't know of any 1D solver that leans itself to parallelization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a parallel [Root-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm)

The [Bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_algorithm), which is a classic [divide and conquer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) can be easily parallelized:
The interval of interest [a,b] can be splitted to n (possibly overlapping) intervals, which may be simultaneously checked for `f(a) < 0 and f(b) > 0 or f(a) > 0 and f(b) < 0`

Some more general and more complex algorithms where suggested. Look [here](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2029190) for example.

Comment: I fail to see how you can parallelize the bisection method.

Comment: You parallelize it by recursively checking each side of a bisection. It's like a binary tree, or like merge sort if you're familiar with that sorting algorithm. You start with a chunk, split it in half, and then proceed with either chunk individually, splitting each of those in half, checking for roots, etc.